# Does Deep Learning based stereo matchers give real depth?

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision, stereo-3d

I know that Deep Learning based monocular depth estimators give relative depth. But are stereo matchers giving relative depth too or do they give real depth?

Comment: depth from monocular vision is equivalent to hallucination or educated guessing (the AI recognizes objects, has learned their size, and figures depth from that). depth from stereo vision *does* give you real distances, assuming the algorithm matched the correct image patches. stereo vision doesn't need AI for the depth estimation but it's probably improving the situation. -- depth from stereo could be said to be relative, if you didn't know the distance between both cameras. since you almost always know though, that distance is the reference, and any depth values are absolute.

Comment: I agree with Christoph.
Stereo triangulation and calibration data gives you the real depth. To do triangulation you need two points in the images (e.g. left and right image) that correspond to the same world point. The AI is today employed to correctly match points between the two. But after matching the underlying process is pure geometry and math.

Monocular images cannot give correct measures, just a guess.